# Why I can't use rabbitmq.config?

Tags: rabbitmq

I don't see `rabbitmq.config` in `/etc/rabbitmq` so I download it from [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/master/docs/rabbitmq.conf.example)

If I directly execute `systemctl restart rabbitmq-server.service` it can work

But when I　modify　`## {loopback_users, [<<"guest">>]},` to `## {loopback_users, []}` it can't work, what happen? What should I do?

the error occur

```
$ systemctl restart rabbitmq-server.service
Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```